# How can I delete a file and an item from a list at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, database, function, select, operating-system

As a result, this is similar to a database; the user must be reminded by the reminder displayed in the program entered by another user. My issue is: how will I be able to delete or remove the file of the selected reminder from the directory so that the reminders are organized into a list?

This is the code:

```
def deleteReminder():
    os.remove(# What to put here?>)
    lb.delete(ANCHOR)
```

Comment: what's `lb`? what's `ANCHOR`? how is `deleteReminder()` called?

Answer (score 0):

Readers cannot know "lb" and "ANCHOR".
Anyway, the function "os.remove" takes "file_path" as input.